# Check if array exists, then either ++ or set standard value

Tags: php, arrays

I found a lot of threads about this but I still can't figure it out.

This code is working for me, but how can I write it in a more efficient way (I have PHP7)?

```
if( isset($statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count']) ) { $statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count']++; } else { $statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] = 1; }
```

This did not work, and isn't a lot more compact code:

```
$statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] = isset($statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count']) ? $statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count']++ : 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt would work, you just need the increment operator at the beginning of the variable:

```
$statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] = isset($statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count']) ? ++$statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] : 1;
```

At the beginning means "*perform the increment then return*". At the end means "*return then perform the increment*".

You could also shorten to:

```
$statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] = ($statsArr['Status'][$s_id]['count'] ?? 0) + 1;
```

This takes advantage of the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) added in 7.0